# PHP template system, image paths

Tags: php, image, templates, file, path

I'm making a basic templating system in PHP, the problem is:

I have a main request handler where from where everything is loaded and processed, but because of that the paths inside the CSS template I downloaded aren't correct anymore.

Example :

```
<img src="assets/images/contact.gif" />
```

has to be:

```
<img src="templates/grey-box/assets/images/contact.gif" />
```

Is there any way to fix this, PHP wise?

Comment: Can you show us the source of the css/php files?

Comment: complete project : http://www.mediafire.com/?43w1kgtcpijj8er

Comment: mediafire.com/?43w1kgtcpijj8er is broken now ("Invalid or Deleted File").

Answer (score 3):

**Don't be lazy**

1. Always use an **absolute path**.
2. Make it explicit, not with some dirty hacks. It will be a support nightmare.
3. You can use some helper variables, like `$tpl_assets_path` and use it in the template.

Absolute path starts  from `/` where `/` designates web-seite root.
And every path on your HTML page should be.

So, the template should be either

```
<img src="/templates/grey-box/assets/images/contact.gif" />
```

or

```
<img src="<?=$tpl_assets_path?>images/contact.gif" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.myhomeurl.com/');
<img src="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER?>assets/images/contact.gif />
```

Comment: That would still require manual change on every link, that isn't any better then it would be to change it by hand.

Answer (score -3):

it's here

```
$imgarray = array('assets','script','css');
$tpl = '/templates/grey-box/';
foreach($imgarray as $i){
  $tpldir = $tpl.$i;
  $str = preg_replace("/([^\/])($i)([\/])/i","\$1$tpldir\$3",$str);
}
```

Comment: This is more file formatting, I suppose that the guy want to be able to change the path easily and not with file formatting